# JavaFX HTMLEditor text wrap

Tags: java, html, css, javafx-2

Is there a way to make a [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) text wrap in JavaFX?

- [TextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) has the method [setWrapText](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#setWrapText%28boolean%29).
- HTML can have text wrapping set through CSS.
- The [JavaFX CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) specifies `-fx-wrap-text` for Labeled nodes, but that doesn't seem to work.

To be specific, the following code doesn't make the text wrap:

```
HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
htmlEditor.setStyle("-fx-text-wrap: false;");
```

Comment: I think I figured it out - a css tag in the body of the html code in the HTMLEditor does the trick. Since the area already allows html formatting, I guess FX wasn't so concerned with empowering the setStyle option; it would be a little redundant.